# Is it possible to host an arbitrary d3 graph on plotly?

Tags: d3.js, plotly, embedly

I would like to make an interactive d3 graph that can be shared on Medium, and to do that I need to use Plotly. However, instead of using plotly to make my graph, I would like to just use d3 -- basically I mainly need plotly for hosting. So, is there a way to host an arbitrary d3 graph on plotly?

Or, I don't really need plotly at all -- I know that Medium uses Embed.ly, and Plotly is supported by Embed.ly. So I really just need to be able to embed a D3 graph in a way that is supported by Embed.ly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself, which is to use observable: https://observablehq.com/@d3